# Print channel content for content that has same field value

Tags: expressionengine

With Expression Engine I need to show the other available jobs when on a jobs page. Jobs are either contract or permanent, and on the jobs page I need to only show other jobs of the same type.

The following prints all the other jobs as well as their type:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" dynamic="no"}                                 
        <p>{title}
        {job_type}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This would print all contact jobs only:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" search:job_type="Contract" dynamic="no"}                                  
        <p>{title}
        {job_type}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

So, I tried using the {job_type} field to refine the search results. However with the following I get no results at all:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" search:job_type="{job_type}" dynamic="no"}                                
        <p>{title}
        {job_type}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Someone said I needed to use PHP tags, so I tried the following, but it returns all the results:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" search:job_type="<?=$this->EE->input->get('job_type')?>" dynamic="no"}                                
        <p>{title}
        {job_type}</p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

How can I achieve what I need? Im new to EE but I would have thought this would be somewhat standard stuff?

Note, the URL structure doesn't allow me to use url segments to filter results. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest `{exp:channel:entries}` tags, as it leads to variable collisions. You'll need to use an [embedded template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding_templates.html) for this, and pass the `{job_type}` value to that template.

So within your main `{exp:channel:entries}` loop:

```
{embed="embeds/more_jobs" job_type="{job_type}"}
```

Then your **embeds/job_type** template looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" search:job_type="{embed:job_type}" dynamic="no"}                                
    <p>{title}
    {job_type}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```